# What does 你就是个托 mean, which 文佳佳 yells at Frank in the movie 北京遇上西雅图 (Finding Mr. Right)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, spoken

In the movie [北京遇上西雅图](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding_Mr._Right) (~13m45s), after not immediately getting her way about her room 文佳佳 yells at Frank who is helping her with her luggage:

> [image: photo of my TV]
> <sub>([Alternative image link](https://i.postimg.cc/Vv0JwHF7/vCNXh.jpg).)</sub>
>
> **你就是个托** 我算是看清楚了

It means "you are a 托" and is some kind of insult, but I don't know what [托](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%89%98) means in this context.  It makes no sense to me (maybe it's related to [衬托](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%A1%AC%E6%89%98)).  The CC-CEDICT definitions are:

> prop / support (for weight) / rest (e.g. arm rest) / thanks to / to hold in one's hand / to support in one's palm / to give / to base / to commit / to set / torr (unit of pressure)
> to trust / to entrust / to be entrusted with / to act as trustee

**Question**: What does 你就是个托 mean in this context?

Comment: 托 is a noun here. It's often been 儿化.  This dictionary definition helps: 帮助行骗者诱人上当的人
E. g. 
他是个托儿。

Comment: Perhaps, its English equivalent can be a 'shill'? Hope English speakers can help to confirm it or suggest another alternative words or phrases. Thanks!

Comment: Not native speaker but I believe shill is accurate. You can also say that person is a decoy, or they are hired/paid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"托" is a verb, meaning "perform intermediary, agency-like activity as the third party". For example, "我想托你办事" means "I want you to perform intermediary activity for me, solving my issues". In china, the third-party agency or intermediary amounted a negative reputation for often exploiting both sides by making use of information asymmetry.

"托儿", aka 托er,  is a derogatory noun for someone who performs agency activities. Usually, the "托儿" pretends to be a neutral third-party (without [COI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest)) to build buyer's trust, but what he actually does is to help the merchants to sell below-standard merchandise to the buyers.

In your specific case, Tang Wei thought Xiubo was her friend, but later she was unsatisfied, therefore thinking Xiubo as a for-profit agency who exploits her ignorance.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, "托" means the person who pretend to involve an activity or to support someone to perform a scam typically.
It is related to 衬托, but derogatory sense only.